# Team System notification of unassociated checkins

Tags: tfs

How can I be notified when someone checks a file into Team System and doesn't associate it with a work item?

Answer (score 1):

Use the very cool team foundation server event subscription tool.  You can find the tool here: http://www.codeplex.com/tfseventsubscription.  Once installed, setup a subscription with the following parameters:

- XPath:   PolicyOverrideComment <> ''
- Event:   CheckinEvent